# C# passing warning message to Modal to render in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Quite simple, just trying to pass an error message to the view if the user's email address isn't found

```
  access.Message = "We have no record of your email <a href=\"www.google.com\"> need help? </a>";
```

My problem is it renders in the view as is, how can I render the href to be a clickable link?

I tried

```
access.Message = "We have no record of your email" +  <a href=\"www.google.com\">  + "need help? </a>";
```

and

```
access.Message = "We have no record of your email @Actionlink(\"www.google.com\", need help?)";
```

Update, actual controller passing value

```
ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError("Error", accessResult.Message);
                    actionResult = View(model);
```

Comment: @Html.Raw(access.Message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when the browser sees this:

> "We have no record of your email 
>   <href=\"www.google.com\"> need help? ";

It will interpret it as a string and just show it. Of course you have html in there but you are telling the browser it is a string so it will treat it that way.

To accomplish what you need, you need to tell the browser it is not a string but contains code so it can do what you want it it to do-interpret the string as code instruction. To do that do this:

```
@Html.Raw(access.Message)
```

That instructs the browser to treat the `Message` as instructions containing raw HTML instructions (code).

Comment: Hey there, thank you for the explaination, it gets rendered using @Html.ValidationSummary(false) I've since tried @Html.Raw(@Html.ValidationSummary(false)) but it still doesn't work correctly.

Comment: `@Html.ValidationSummary` produces a string which ends up as an attribute in the element. So to achieve what you want you will need to write javascript so when the validation is triggered, you show an html element. This html element can be your message with a link.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Need Help?", "yourAction", "yourController")
```

In your "yourAction" method

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      return Redirect("http://www.google.com"); // redirects to external url
    }
```